# What's the best way to manage many requests from the same API?

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I'm working with a json API using python requests, the company who issued the API doesn't clarify in its documentation how many requests I can make per day/hour/minute.

Sometimes I am getting connection errors with it, is there any way to systematically deal with that? find out what the limits are or some way to test what they are efficiently?

Thank you.

Comment: Count the number of requests you're making until you start getting errors. Maybe that will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an expert in this and your question was pretty vague so I can't really tell in what way you need to systematically deal with the problems that arise.

If it is something that is already running and only occasionaly fails due connection errors or request limits then I would suggest programming something that helps you track the requests and answers from the server by writing them into a text file so you can check later what the error message was and why it happened. To make it easier to go over this data you can have it as an object in your code and save it as a json or xml file so that you can open it and have it as an object again in python.

For example you could have an object that saves the number of requests you have sent, the number of errors you have gotten, a list of requests you have sent, a list of answers you have gotten from the server and a list with numbers of which requests have failed.

If it is something small scale or something that isn't working yet then I would suggest just going over the errors manually and just try to see if you can fix them. You could send alot of requests manually to check the request limit and you could try to find out what happens when a connection error occurrs and try to recognize that in python and send the request again.